# Dynamic Leader For Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, leader-line

I am creating set of charts in arcmap using data driven pages
I can highlight the active page in the key map as shown in the picture but I want to create a dynamic leader to point to the current page. is that possible?

[image]

Comment: I think there's an option in overview extent indicators which might be as close as you'll get https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/using-extent-indicators-to-enhance-overview-or-locator-maps.htm without ArcObjects.

Comment: Where is the leader coming from?